# Comparing Strings in Grails GSP

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-3.0

I'm stumped by this problem. I'm trying to display a class if a certain string is equals to the logged in username. However it doesn't seem to ever evaluate to true.
Here's the code in gsp

```
<g:if test="${it.from.username == sec.loggedInUserInfo(field: 'username')}">
   <div class="direct-chat-msg right">
</g:if>
<g:else>
   <div class="direct-chat-msg">
</g:else>
```

I also tried using this method

```
<div class="direct-chat-msg ${(it.from.username == sec.loggedInUserInfo(field: 'username')) ? 'right' : ''}">
```

However nothing I do can get the 'right' class to show up in the div.
Just for good measure, I printed out the values of both classes in my gsp in hidden fields.

```
<input type="hidden" value="${it.from.username}"/>
<input type="hidden" value="${sec.loggedInUserInfo(field: 'username')}"/>
```

And the values are exactly the same

```
<input type="hidden" value="u***@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" value="u***@gmail.com">
```

I've tried several combinations of string comparison
`.equals()`, calling `.toString()` on both, also trying `as String`. however nothing seems to be working.
What could the issue be?

I have tried passing the logged in user object in the Model from the controller, and just calling `loggedInUser.username` and it works. So my question now is, what kind of object is returned by spring security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `sec.loggedInUserInfo(field: 'username')}` is an HTML encoded string. Spring security calls `encodeAsHTML()` before returning `'username'` value. Visually they look the same but are they equal? Apparently not!